# Some specific case of the abc-conjecture related to the Mason-Stothers proof of Serge Lang for polynomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, inequalities, derivations, abc-conjecture

I stumbled upon a version of the Mason-Stothers theorem, which can be modified to make a similar statement for natural numbers, which I think I can prove [here](http://www.orges-leka.de/the_mason-stothers_theorem_for_integers.pdf). It is *not* the abc-conjecture, but it has similarities to it ( See the "Edit" section).

Here are some details relevant for the question:

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $n':=n \sum_{p|n} \frac{v_p(n)}{p}$ denote the arithmetic derivative, which according to Wikipedia was introduced by the Spanish mathematician Josè Mingot Shelly in 1911.

It satisfies the Leibniz Rule:

\begin{equation}
(mn)' = m'n + mn'
\end{equation}

It is known that there is an analogy between polynomials and natural numbers. Using this analogy, we define the polynomials, given the natural number $n$:

\begin{equation}
f_n(x) = \prod_{p|n, p \text{ prime }} \left ( x+p \right )^{v_p(n)}
\end{equation}

It has the property, that when putting $x=0$ we get the number $n$ back and the derivatives for $x=0$ coincide:

\begin{equation}
f_n(0) = n
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_n'(x)|_{x=0} = n'
\end{equation}

Let $\operatorname{rad}(n):=\prod_{p|n}p$ denote the radical of the natural number $n$ and let:

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{rad}(g(x)) := \prod_{\alpha \in \Omega_g} x-\alpha
\end{equation}

where $\Omega_g:=$ is the set of distinct roots of $g$.

Let $m,n$ be two natural numbers with $\gcd(m,n)=1$,  such that:
\begin{equation}
W(m,n):= m'n-mn' \neq 0
\end{equation}
where $W(m,n)$ denotes the Wronskian of the arithmetic derivative.
Let $g(x) := f_m(x) + f_n(x)$. Then we have the following inequality:

\begin{equation}
mn(m+n) \le \operatorname{rad}(mn) \left | \operatorname{rad(g(x))|_{x=0}} \right | \cdot |W(m,n)|
\end{equation}

My question is, after doing some experiments in SageMath, if it can be proved that:

$$|\operatorname{rad}(g(x))|_{x=0} \frac{|W(m,n)|}{mn} \le \operatorname{rad}(m+n)^2 \operatorname{rad}(mn)$$

which I think would prove the abc-conjecture for $\epsilon = 1$ and $K_{\epsilon} = 1$, if it is not asked too much.

**Edit**:
I realized that maybe it is better to prove the Mason-Stothers theorem for natural numbers with the method from Serge Lang in this version, and then apply it to some specific polynomials:

Let $f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{N}[x]$ be two polynomials with $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=1$, $f(0)\neq 0 , g(0) \neq 0$ and let $F(x):=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+g(x)}, G(x) :=\frac{g(x)}{f(x)+g(x)}$ and suppose that $F'(0) \neq 0,G'(0) \neq 0$. Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{g(0)}{\gcd(f(0),g(0))} \le \operatorname{rad}(f(x)g(x)(f(x)+g(x)))|_{x=0} |F'(0)/F(0)|
\end{equation}

The polynomials which I am considering are $f(x):=f_{m^2n}(x),g(x):=g_{mn^2}(x)$, which when applied to the last inequality yield under some assumptions a specific form of the abc-conjecture inequality:

Let $m,n$ be two natural numbers with $\gcd(m,n)=1, W(m,n) \neq 0, mn > |W(m,n)|$ and
$$ \operatorname{rad}(f_m(x)+f_n(x))|_{x=0} \le \operatorname{rad}(m+n)$$.
Then:
\begin{equation}
m+n < \operatorname{rad}(mn(m+n))
\end{equation}

The proof can be given like this, I think:

Consider in the last proposition $f(x):=f_{m^2n}(x), g(x):=f_{mn^2}(x)$ with
$$\gcd(f(0),g(0)) = \gcd(m^2n,mn^2) = mn$$ and $\operatorname{rad}(f(x)g(x))|_{x=0} = \operatorname{rad}(mn)$ and $|F'(0)/F(0)| = \frac{|W(m,n)|}{m(m+n)}$. Then we get:

\begin{equation}
n = \frac{n^2m}{mn} = \frac{g(0)}{\gcd(f(0),g(0))} \le \operatorname{rad}(mn) \operatorname{rad}(f(x)+g(x))|_{x=0} \cdot |F'(0)/F(0)| 
\end{equation}

which leads to :

\begin{equation}
n  \le  \operatorname{rad}(mn)\operatorname{rad}(f(x)+g(x))|_{x=0} \cdot\frac{|W(m,n)|}{m(m+n)}
\end{equation}

hence by multiplying with $m(m+n)$ we get:

\begin{equation}
mn(m+n) \le \operatorname{rad}(mn)\operatorname{rad}(f(x)+g(x))|_{x=0} |W(m,n)| 
\end{equation}

which by assumptions is
\begin{equation}
mn(m+n) \le \operatorname{rad}(mn)\operatorname{rad}(f(x)+g(x))|_{x=0} |W(m,n)| < mn \operatorname{rad}(mn(m+n))
\end{equation}

and the inequality follows when dividing by $mn$.

**Modified question:** Are there an infinite number of $(m,n)$ which satisfy the assumptions of the mentioned proposition above:

$$\gcd(m,n)=1, 0 < |W(m,n)| < mn , \operatorname{rad}(f_m(x)+f_n(x))|_{x=0} \le \operatorname{rad}(m+n)$$
?

[SageMath-Code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFUk1v4yAQvVvyfxh1DwWHTdJrtc6xvUd7alWtcIwdVDMgwIn773ew5XXj_eICzMfjvTfUqgEva4b8Mc-Allex9wjO25o5r436UeuLDtYHquF5lmc1tdTK68tvTaE37BUusutl1BYZCsd3DhrrwYFOoCu8N17gDOlsRw3Dn3iwYeN4UdwC_wN2pDmhHklbu6Bq46yPgL1xHyADoJviNZSTJsK_qLHjhgZrd-0pIa2KpqeO1P3y8no_3L_l2UCX47ZVyD7RuHqL4V1LZEasXZu8NGTF19nWwkytedZ0siXA775X8AXiWQc4SYRKQVARooUn2QUlKKMQdISWmAWQXQdqkMZ1dBmfFHA969MZAnEPzUeqJ_00MJcMDQLQRrDYpYwNCq46nsePYTbI4RvQts0zchojuyNAQQEx56dDgcV443c8qSPuNCCZBuQltoo9iIf9fj-LT8nqb8m0kuzkuRQVX6L09Gg2k7uWC9or2pf0MyXTRzI0m838o5a0bmA1irLcAzFJ3-SZSrehr0LUsY-KDeWeH5KySVUqk1Vgt_38UJLwT7TTOlmMGnu1RBUN6RFuq4gMAR9-mSyxhjTuFVhak-__sZ3_BKcvFUs=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to produce examples which satisfy the assumptions:

```
def rad(n):
    return prod(prime_divisors(n))

def deriv(n):
    return sum([ valuation(n,p)/p for p in prime_divisors(n)])*n

def pol(n,x):
    return prod((x+p)**valuation(n,p) for p in prime_divisors(n))


def Rad(g,x):
    import numpy as np
    d = derivative(g,x)
    return (g/gcd(g,derivative(g,x)))

R = ZZ['x']
x = R.gen()


def wronskian(m,n):
    return deriv(m)*n-deriv(n)*m



flag = True # this can be set to False, then it gives all examples (m,n), which satisfy the assumptions, not only those with rad(m+n) < m+n.
print("m,n,m+n,rad(m+n),rad(m*n*(m+n))")    
for a in range(1,1000):
    for b in range(1,1000):
        g = gcd(a,b)
        m,n = ZZ(a/g),ZZ(b/g)
        G = pol(m,x)+pol(n,x)
        if  wronskian(m,n)==0 or Rad(G,x).substitute(x=0)>rad((m+n)) or abs(wronskian(m,n))>=m*n:
            continue
        else: 
            if m+n>rad(m+n) and flag:
                print(m,n,m+n,rad(m+n),rad(m*n*(m+n)))
```

which gives at the beginning the output:

```
m,n,m+n,rad(m+n),rad(m*n*(m+n))
1 35 36 6 210
1 899 900 30 26970
1 35 36 6 210
3 17 20 10 510
3 41 44 22 2706
3 73 76 38 8322
3 89 92 46 12282
1 35 36 6 210
3 113 116 58 19662
3 137 140 70 28770
3 233 236 118 82482
3 241 244 122 88206
3 257 260 130 100230
3 281 284 142 119706
3 313 316 158 148362
3 337 340 170 171870
3 353 356 178 188502
3 401 404 202 243006
3 409 412 206 252762
3 433 436 218 283182
3 449 452 226 304422
3 457 460 230 315330
3 521 524 262 409506
3 569 572 286 488202
```

Comment: So now the abc conjecture is called the Mason-Strothers Theorem for integers? Anyway, "the set of distinct roots of $g$" – in which field?

Comment: To give credit where credit is due, the $abc$-conjecture for $\mathbb Z$ was formulated by Osterle and Masser.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: In $\mathbb{C}$. I called it the Mason-Stothers theorem for integers, because of the proof I mimicked in Serge's Lang 'Algebra', which was about the Mason-Stothers theorem. I am aware that the abc-conjecture was formulated by Osterle and Masser. Sorry for not being clear about this.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: Thanks for the reminder. I am aware of this, but since I was inspired by the proof of Serge Lang for the Mason-Stothers theorem, this is why I wrote in the title "Mason-Stothers theorem for natural numbers". I did not want to offend anybody by not giving appropriate credit.